# Advice for handling file uploads w/ metadata (S3 and Node/Express)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, architecture

I'm building a service with node/express hosted on AWS that accepts photo uploads. The photos are going to be stored in S3 but will be restricted to users with certain permissions (application defined). The access will be controlled via signed S3 URLs created by the node servers.

The clients uploading the photos will be iOS, Android and modern browsers.

To maximize scalability I intended to have the clients upload the photos directly to S3 so my servers don't need to handle these requests. This requires the clients to get a signed upload URL from the server prior to uploading the photo. The challenge I'm facing is the photos can be paired with user-defined metadata that I store in a database (e.g. photo caption, notes etc). I'm trying to avoid having orphaned photos or metadata. If I require the client to upload the metadata to the database first then there's a chance the photo fails to upload and vice versa.

What options do I have for making this work? Here's what I've come up with so far:

1. Store the photo captions as [user-defined metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#UserMetadata) on the S3 object. This could work but has limitations (US-ASCII only text and all lowercase).
2. Move photo upload endpoint to an AWS Lambda method. Now that Lambda supports access to resources in a VPC the Lambda method could handle writing the photo metadata to the database after streaming the photo to S3. And since Lambda would be running outside my application server I wouldn't need to worry about load on the application server.
3. Handle photo uploads on the application server and worry about scale if it becomes a problem. I have a similar server running ASP.NET in a shared hosting environment and have run into concurrent connection limit problems but that might just be shared hosting. I'm assuming I can configure the load balancer on AWS to spin up instances as needed for this condition.
4. Require the clients to upload the photos first to S3 then upload the captions in a second transaction against the node server. Worst-case scenario is the user's captions are lost.

What other options would you recommend?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Upload the metadata with a status of "pending" or something like that.  Then upload the image as per your question.  Have a lambda trigger on your bucket that updates the status.

For bonus marks, a timed lambda function that cleans out old records with "pending" status.